# JSON is Malformed - AWS Personalize Input File

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

I'm trying to filter Recommendations with AWS Personalize.
Here is my data:

```
{"userId":"102155","filterValues":{"vehicleList":"\"487392\",\"136579\",\"389046\",\"454400\",\"108908\",\"172677\",\"552009\",\"140498\",\"575257\",\"141883\",\"82165\",\"271906\",\"349764\",\"555072\",\"487997\",\"445148\",\"377268\",\"155944\",\"695511\",\"42694\",\"2688\",\"686149\",\"428393\",\"303605\",\"315137\",\"429949\",\"36664\",\"399623\",\"255099\",\"198335\""}}
```

d

From using JSON lint and my eyes it seems like its structured accordingly to their documentation, yet I keep getting the Malformed JSON error.

Any help is very welcome! It was working before I added the filterValues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the structure of the json above. Filtervalues should look more like:

```
,"filterValues":{"vehicleList":"\"677186\",\"620751\"
```

Fixed the issue.